# How to integrate Angular 5 app in Javascript/JQuery app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, integration

The main client application that I am working with is written in Javascript/JQuery.

The task I need to accomplish is to create a chatbot that would be independent from the root application. Just by pressing a button somewhere on the page a chatbox should come up and allow the user to interact with the bot. It was decided to write the chatbot application in Angular 5. How can I integrate this Angular app into the parent Javascript application?

Thank you very much!

Comment: host your angular app somewhere and use iframe

Comment: Or send the requests to directly to your server using jQuery instead of using angular